# making table with data.frame in R

Tags: r

How can I make my data frame or make a table from

```
   TIME_PERIOD MARRIAGE_LICENSES
1      2011-01               742
2      2011-02               796
3      2011-03              1210
4      2011-04              1376
....
```

To something that looks like

```
      01  02  03   04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11 11
2011 742 796 1210 1376 
2012
2013
2014
2015
```

and so on?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  We expect you to try to write the program on your own.  Then you post your code and the output you got; we help fix the problem.  In this case, you need to make a table with 13 columns: year and 12 months.  Split the year-month data at the hyphen; use the two parts as the row data (year) and column index (month).   Does that get you going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `data.table` as:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dcast(dat, format(TIME_PERIOD, "%Y") ~ format(TIME_PERIOD, "%m"),
      value.var = "MARRIAGE_LICENSES")
```

(note: requires `MARRIAGE_LICENSE` to be stored as a `Date` or other object which has an appropriate `format` method first)

Answer (score 1):

Using `reshape2` you can do the following (which gives you a `data.frame`)

```
require(reshape2)
dat$year <- as.numeric(substr(dat$TIME_PERIOD,1,4))
dat$month <- as.numeric(substr(dat$TIME_PERIOD,6,8))

require(reshape2)
dcast(dat, year~month, value.var = "MARRIAGE_LICENSES")
```

This gives you

```
  year   1   2    3    4
1 2011 742 796 1210 1376
```

If you want to have your format and the years as rownames do:

```
df <- dcast(dat, year~month, value.var = "MARRIAGE_LICENSES")
rownames(df)  <- df$year
df[,-1]
```

Resulting in

```
       1   2    3    4
2011 742 796 1210 1376
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
library(tidyr) ## for separate()
xtabs(MARRIAGE_LICENSES ~ ., separate(df, TIME_PERIOD, c("year", "month"), "-"))
#       month
# year     01   02   03   04
#   2011  742  796 1210 1376
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(TIME_PERIOD = structure(1:4, .Label = c("2011-01", 
"2011-02", "2011-03", "2011-04"), class = "factor"), MARRIAGE_LICENSES = c(742L, 
796L, 1210L, 1376L)), .Names = c("TIME_PERIOD", "MARRIAGE_LICENSES"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```